# CSS z-index - Can't set the box to be outside the div

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I have the following code:
http://codepad.org/cL3hjDTf

Black box which contains text 'Some text' should be outside of the box marked with blue border. It should look like
[image]

But I can't achieve this effect. Where I made mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript you have up in that single line is applying inline styles that set overflow hidden to the wrapper. To test, use overflow: visible !important; in your CSS and it should force it to work.

Don't do that though. Take it out of the Javascript. However, I suspect that the carrosel will look a bit strange either way as that wrapper hides the slides that aren't visible.

Your best bet would be to increase the height of wrapper to include the "Some text" span's bottom offset (-25px) padding would do it.

```
.carousel-wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

span {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You should take `overflow:hidden` off of `.carousel-wrapper`

Comment: This didn't work because the javascript applies it inline to that element. It is needed because it hides the slides that aren't currently meant to be visible. Taking it off would break the carousel.

Answer (score 0):

Youll need to set `overflow: visible` not hidden as you have it now on .carousel-wrapper